# Any reward for defeating Cuccoos?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I first encountered a Cuccoo in the Great Fairy Fountain of Faron Woods. Zelda logic dictates that attacking a Cuccoo is *a very bad idea.* However, Zelda logic also dictates *that thou must*. For giggles (Link, Hero of Hyrule!).

So I set about carving myself off a drumstick and, inevitably, soon had an army of angry drumsticks making life miserable for my brave comrades (Link, Hero of Hyrule!).

After beating up the leader, a new, shining, *golden* Cuccoo appeared with about 5 times the health and designs on a new green hat. Shiny gold things usually mean *treasure*, so I abandoned Faron Woods and its defenders to their fate, in pursuit of personal riches (Link, Hero of Hyrule!).

Sadly, after defeating the Golden Cuccoo, nothing happened other than the rest of the Cuccoos fleeing the field. Not so much as a Rupee was dropped from the fallen hen.

Is there any benefit at all to fighting the Cuccoos and their golden leader?

Comment: According to the Wiki, it serves as a General; other than that, it doesn't appear to be anything other than an amusing distraction/easter egg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is purely a distraction there is no reward for defeating them, although if you can get an enemy to attack them they will fight the enemy's while you sit back and watch.

This is the article from wiki: http://zeldawiki.org/Cucco#Hyrule_Warriors

Although it doesn't tell you if they drop anything I can confirm that from personal experience.